# Churn Rate in R

Tags: r

I have a data set named df_a running in millions. I want to calculate the churn rate and group into months.

On the sample data I ran the code to prepare my data.
The logic is to find the minimum month(acquired month)
find the last month based on the records
find the difference in months and group the difference in months

The code below

```
df_a<-data.table(df)

df_a[,"min_date" := min(yw), by=c("CUSTOMER_DIMENSION_ID")]
df_a[,"max_date" := max(yw), by=c("CUSTOMER_DIMENSION_ID")]

df_a$min_date_m<-anydate(df_a$min_date)
df_a$max_date_m<-anydate(df_a$max_date)

df_a$diff_days <- df_a$max_date_m - df_a$min_date_m
df_a$difference <- as.numeric(df_a$diff_days) /(365.25/12)


df_a$Month_Bucket<-ifelse((df_a$difference>=0 & df_a$difference<3),"3",
                          ifelse((df_a$difference>=3 & df_a$difference<6),"3-6",
                          ifelse((df_a$difference>=6 & df_a$difference<9),"6-9",
                          ifelse((df_a$difference>=9 & df_a$difference<12),"9-12",              
                          ifelse((df_a$difference>=12 & df_a$difference<24),"12-24",                
                                        "24+")))))


data_a <- df_a[c(1,1:nrow(df_a)),]
setDT(data_a)

  xxx<-(cohorts <-dcast(unique(data_a)[,cohort:=min(yw),by=CUSTOMER_DIMENSION_ID],cohort~Month_Bucket))
```

I am getting the output in the following format

```
Month        3                                                          
2020-08     92876                                                                 
2020-07     144873
```

However the output is not correct

What I want is

```
Month      no of unique customers acquired  0-3  3-6 6-9  
2019-08       85749
2019-07      128060
```

The output basically is summing up the customers across months and assigning a bucket. However if I acquire 85749 customers in 2019-08 i will have lets say 25k customers in 0-3 25k again in 3-6 months

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use to provide answers. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One here could do :

```
data_unique <- unique(data_a)

ccc <- ( cohorts <- dcast( data_unique[ , 
                                       cohort := min(yw), 
                                       by=CUSTOMER_DIMENSION_ID], 
             cohort ~ Month_Bucket,
             value.var = "CUSTOMER_DIMENSION_ID",
             function(x) { length(unique(x) } ) ) 
)
```